# отправка ссылки в телеграм-канал

Tags: python, python-3.x, requests, telegram

есть длинная ссылка вида:

```
https://mysite.com/...&.../
```

пытаюсь ее отправить через requests в свой канал сообщением вида:

```
r = requests.get(https://api.telegram.org/bot...:.../sendMessage?chat_id=@mychannel&text=ссылка)
```

сообщение уходит, но ссылка обрезается на `&`.
как исправить и заставить телеграм отправлять полную ссылку?

Answer (score 0):

### JSON

Если уж используешь для отправки python, а не обычный браузер - отправляй параметры к методу в формате JSON. Их проще формировать, читать и изменять на лету.

```py
import requests
requests.post(url, json={"key": "value"})
```

### Фреймворки

Лучше всего использовать уже [готовые инструменты](https://aiogram.dev/). Посмотри насколько это просто:

```py
from aiogram import Bot


async def main():
    # создаём бота
    bot = Bot('твой:токен')

    # отправляем сообщение
    await bot.send_message('канал', 'ссылка')

    # закрываем бота
    await bot.close()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: не понял, как отправить с get запросом что то в формате json? по aiogram требует python 3.7.0+ а у меня версия 3.6+, может другая библиотека есть?

Comment: Питон ставится за несколько минут, при этом не убивает предыдущие версии. Ещё есть telebot, там, вроде, ниже версия нужна (но он и не поддерживает последнюю версию Telegram API). О том, как отправлять json можете просто погуглить или прочитать в документации к requests

Comment: Добавил пример с requests json